# WebGL and problems with local server + VScode

Tags: javascript, webgl, localserver

I am following a tutorial in the basics of WebGL. I have written the code to produce a basic triangle with the console warnings-

```
webGL warning: enableVertexAttribArray: -1 is not a valid `index`. This value probably comes from a getAttribLocation() call, where this return value -1 means that the passed name didn't correspond to an active attribute in the specified program.
WebGL warning: vertexAttribI?Pointer: `index` (4294967295) must be < MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS.
```

I am new to development and my question is; why I can only see my html  tag when loading with wsl on local server?
I have used Node.js and Express.js packages. I am using VScode & Mozilla Firefox.

Here is the code of the main.js file;

```
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");

if (!gl) {
  throw new Error("webgl not supported");
}

alert(`Everything is working`);


const vertexData = [0, 1, 0, 1, -1, 0, -1, -1, 0];

const buffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertexData), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

// VERTEX SHADER
const vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(
  vertexShader,
  `
attribute vec3 position;
void main() {
gl_Position = vec4(position, 1);
}
`
);
gl.compileShader(vertexShader);

// FRAGMENT SHADER
const fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(
  fragmentShader,
  `
void main (){
  gl_FragColor= vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);
}
`
);
gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);

const program = gl.createProgram();
gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
gl.linkProgram(program);

const positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(
  program,
  `
position`
);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

gl.useProgram(program);
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
```

**html file;**

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="main.js" defer></script>
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>hello webGL!!</h1>
    <canvas></canvas>
  </body>

  <!-- async run the script but runin particular order of run
  advantage you dont have to use DOM contect in js file -->
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? In web development it’s common practice to open a webpage on localhost instead of directly opening the html file in your file system. For the above code you don’t need nodejs or express

Comment: Thank you for your response @Kokodoko - The triangle isnt showing up on the page. I have opened the webpage up with localhost:5500/ as I have directed in the server.js ; ```const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.listen(5500);
```
I seem to be opening the web browser within my file directory , when i 'go live' the local host opens a page with folders on it. I have come across this before and cant remember the v simple fix it requires. 
Also can you explain why Node and express are not needed with WebGL?

Comment: `getAttribLocation()` returns that -1 (it means "not found" in many-many contexts), because there's a linebreak before "position". Remove it, and it will work. Don't use backticks, only when you need them (like for actual multi-line text, or for string interpolation).

Comment: Ah yes, nice catch. Removing the line break fixes it: https://jsfiddle.net/bLecjrvy/

Comment: Ah I see. This tutorial may not be the best practice then. After removing the backticks, I have many more errors. What would be your best advice when learning WebGL other than WebGL fundamentals webpage? 
I just saw your answer and ran the code on here, it works here but not on my web browser, when I load the local host I am given my file directory. back to the basics of opening the file in ubuntu . cd projects - cd webglfile - code .
am I opening inside the wrong folder or something to see the file directory on the page in localhost:5500 instead of that impressive triangle?

Comment: You are describing two different problems though :) Problem one is that you have to realise backticks behave different from normal quotation marks. Backticks give you the opportunity to use line breaks and continue a string on the next line. You cannot do that with normal quotes. It's up to you to decide when you need that functionality. The other problem is that your server doesn't open your page correctly but instead shows a directory. But it's not clear to me why you use node and express in the first place. It's not necessary for WebGL projects.

Comment: Yes there are two problems, I have solved the second one. I have been following along with a course, I too do not understand why I am using Node or express. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");

if (!gl) {
  throw new Error("webgl not supported");
}

//alert(`Everything is working`);


const vertexData = [0, 1, 0, 1, -1, 0, -1, -1, 0];

const buffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertexData), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

// VERTEX SHADER
const vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(
  vertexShader,
  `
attribute vec3 position;
void main() {
gl_Position = vec4(position, 1);
}
`
);
gl.compileShader(vertexShader);

// FRAGMENT SHADER
const fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(
  fragmentShader,
  `
void main (){
  gl_FragColor= vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);
}
`
);
gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);

const program = gl.createProgram();
gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
gl.linkProgram(program);

const positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(
  program,
  `position` // <------------------------------------------------------- here
);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

gl.useProgram(program);
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
```

```html
<h1>hello webGL!!</h1>
    <canvas></canvas>
```